# Clarification on unit normal vector to a graph of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

In solving for the unit normal vector $\hat{n}$ of a surface $z=h(x,y)$, the unit normal vector is defined as follows: $$\hat{n}=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$$ with $f=f(x,y,z)=z-h(x,y)$ and $|\nabla f|\neq 0$. My question is, is it also correct to define $f$ as $f=h(x,y)-z$? I think they are the same since $f=z-h(x,y)=0$ and $f=h(x,y)-z=0$ but the following example shows they yield different answers.

Suppose $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Case 1: $f=z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then $\nabla f=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\vec{i}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\vec{j}+\vec{k}$ and $|\nabla f|=\sqrt{2}$. Thus $$\hat{n}=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}}\vec{i}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}}\vec{j}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vec{k}$$ 
Case 2: $f=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-z$. Then $\nabla f=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\vec{i}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\vec{j}-\vec{k}$ and $|\nabla f|=\sqrt{2}$. Thus $$\hat{n}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}}\vec{i}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}}\vec{j}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vec{k}$$ This shows that the $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$ and $\vec{k}$ components are of opposite sign to which I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take $f(x, y, z) := z - h(x, y)$ and $\bar{f} := -f$, then both
$\hat{n} := \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ and $-\hat{n} = \frac{\nabla \bar{f}}{|\nabla \bar{f}|}$ are unit normal vector fields along the graph of $f$. The difference is the following: Computing gives
$$\nabla f = -\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \hat{i} -\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \hat{j} + \hat{k},$$
so the unit normal vector field $\hat{n} = \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ always has positive $z$-component---and so we might call it the *upward-pointing unit normal vector field*---and so $-\hat{n}$ has negative $z$-component. Note that surfaces that are not graphs need not have a unit normal vector field that is upward-pointing in this sense, or even a globally defined unit normal vector field at all.

(By the way, note that $$|\nabla f|^2 = \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)^2 + 1 \geq 1,$$
so the condition $|\nabla f| \neq 0$ always holds everywhere.)

Comment: Sir, thanks. Does that mean Sir that either case is correct when asked to compute for the unit normal vector of a particular surface?

Comment: You're welcome. I would say that both $\hat{n}$ and $-\hat{n}$ are unit normal vector fields along the surface, and that any vector in the field is a unit normal vector to the surface at its base point, but probably people typically have in mind the upward-pointing unit normal unless otherwise specified. (Relatedly, by convention, on a closed surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, one typically takes the outward-pointing unit normal vector field unless specified otherwise.)

Comment: Now I get it Sir. Turns out it's just a matter of the orientation of $\hat{n}$ but I think I have to use the "upward-pointing" $\hat{n}$ when not specified in a problem.

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad my answer was useful.